# IOS form framework

Tags: ios, forms

An iPad app I'm working on will be used by salespeople to fill out an application form that will be then uploaded to a CRM system. My question relates on what's the most efficient design pattern for the "application form".

There are 6 products, each product has a specific application form, and there's one set of application forms per state, so a max of 300 application forms to code for UI and validation.

The application form has be filled out assuming the iPad is offline (upload will be done later) and only one state is loaded at a time (donwloading the state forms is also done later once the device is online and before the salesperson goes on the road).

So it'll be too time consuming to code each specific form in a UI and for the validation checks (what I call the brute force method).

HTML5 Forms is probably not appropriate as it requires the device to be onliine. XFORMS is said to be obsolete and not used any more.

Are there any other standards or frameworks that could be used? Maybe something based on XML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that my XForms implementation (XSLTForms) is used on iPads for offline applications. XForms will continue to be improved as long as users are interested in. You should have a look at the W3C XForms Users Community Group (http://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/) to access the XForms 2.0 Draft Specifications (http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/XForms_2.0).

-Alain

Comment: XSLTForms is a client-side implementation written with XSLT and generating HTML+Javascript instructions. Local storage is supported and a Java applet allows to access files on a local drive.